# Voiceover for Mac: W3C compliance?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I've been doing a lot of testing with accessibility lately, and ARIA in particular. Whenever I test on Apple Voiceover (OS X 10.9.2), the behavior seems non-compliant and sometimes even nondeterministic. This is true even for basic functionality like `role="button"`. However, I recognize the very real possibility that it's user error on my part. (Assume for this question that the markup itself is correct and works perfectly in other screen readers.) So, based on your experience, am I correct that Voiceover is simply bug-ridden and inadequate for testing ARIA-enhanced webpages? Or do I just need to get to know it better?

Comment: Do you have a specific example of something being misinterpreted?

Answer (score 1):

Some things I've learned:

- For now, you should use Safari for best results with Voiceover. Part of my problem was that I was testing in other browsers. Some, or perhaps all, other browsers interact oddly with Voiceover. Perhaps this situation will improve with time.
- Voiceover's user interface can be counterintuitive. By nature, it's not particularly discoverable. [This document](http://help.apple.com/voiceover/vo/en/VOKeysColor_1.html) was very helpful for me. You can't get very far without knowing the subtleties of the keyboard controls.
- You need to use the ctrl-option-shift-up and ctrl-option-shift-down keys to "enter" and "exit" individual DOM nodes. Otherwise, you will be unable to interact with them at times, and will likely get stuck inside them at other times.
- Sometimes things are announced in strange ways. For example, an element like `<span role="button" aria-label="Delete">×</span>` is announced initially as "Delete group." If you enter the button with ctrl-option-shift-down, it announces "1 item interact with delete group times clickable." The first message doesn't include "clickable," which is surprising to me. The second message has a low signal-to-noise ratio, in my opinion. But now I'm just quibbling. `role="button"` may not behave as I'd like or expect it to, but at least it's not ignored. Ditto for many other ARIA attributes.

Comment: Just a few things.. you probably mean `role=button` instead of `aria-role=button`. And `aria-label` is quite inconsistent across screen-readers, OS X simply prepend the label string. For best result use the following inside the `<span role=button>`: `<span aria-hidden=true>x</span>` and add a  `<span class=visually-hidden>Delete</span>` and hide `.visually-hidden` off-screen with CSS
Also instead of `<span role=button` consider using `<button type=button` then you don't have to add `JS` handlers for enter key and spacebar.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Typo. I've edited my post accordingly. As to the other suggestions, they're definitely workable in some situations, but whenever possible I prefer to use the ARIA attributes as specified. Obviously I'm not going to stubbornly follow the spec on something no clients actually support, though.